# Lumen: optional route params isn't resolved correctly

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-10, lumen-routing

Using Laravel's Lumen 9.1.6

I am following the documentation but still have a problem with an optional trailing route parameter defined like this:

**routes/web.php**

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'question'], function() use($router) {  
    $router->get('log/{eid}/{uid}[/{year}]', ['middleware' => 'api.auth', 'uses' => 'QuestionController@getLogs']);
});
```

and then in **QuestionController.php**

```
public function getLogs($eid, $uid, $year = null, Request $request) {
  ....
}
```

If I then call
`api.tld/question/log/1/2/2021` - it works fine, however
`api.tld/question/log/1/2` - throws *Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #2 [  $year ]] in class App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController*

Lumen docs are very sparse on this (although I believe I've followed the syntax correctly). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you passed $year above ? as it's the right way for optional parameter in routes.

Comment: Passed where?... The function will set $year to null, if it is not defined.

Comment: As answered it's quite good and right way but I've tried your way too and it was working fine. Well you find the answer happy coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
public function getLogs(Request $request, $eid, $uid, $year = null) {
  ....
}
```

You have to put request first.